# Extract the names of the files in folders

Tags: c#, directory

I'm working on a project and I'm also wondering how to extract the names of files in folders

e.g. I'm in "CatA" catalog with 2 subfolders:

- "CatAA" with catalog "ExpAA" - aaa.zip inside
- "CatBB" with catalog "ExpBB" - bbb.zip inside

My goal is to list (get the file names) aaa.zip and bbb.zip file while being in a main "CatA" file.

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\CatA");

        //checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(0, dirs.Length);

        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length - 1; i++)
        {
          //c# go a folder up
          dirs.
          var zipFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\DLXP3B3\Desktop\tes", "*.zip");
          checkedListBox1.Items.Insert(i, zipFiles[i]);
        }
```

I have some work done, but I don't know how to proceed. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *but I don't know how to proceed* what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to include option to show all sub directories within your directory:

```
var zipFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\DLXP3B3\Desktop\tes", "*.zip", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `Directory.GetFiles` gives you the path of matching files, If you want the file names alone you have to get the file names,

```
var zipFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\CatA", "*.zip", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                  .Select(x=> Path.GetFileName(x))
                                  .ToArray();
```

Now the `zipFiles` will have the list of all files with extension `.zip`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the complete path of all files in the parent folder use :-

```
var allFilesWithPath = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\CatA", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

If you only need the filename and not the complete path, use the below code :-

```
    var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\CatA", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray();
```